# openlayers - wms layer maxzoom 16, need to zoom more (programatically)

Tags: zooming, openlayers

I have an openlayers map with wms layer on it. The thing is wms server albe to work only with maxzoom 16, while I need it to work with greater zoom levels.

Is there possibility to zoom pragrammatically beyond 16 value? (like NativeZoom in leaflet)

Thanks

Comment: If you are using ImagWMS you can specify a resolution array in the source options.  For TileWMS you can specify maxZoom in the tile grid.  Then you can increase the maxZoom in the view beyond 16.

Comment: any samples appreciated

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-image-5vodd and https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-tiled-rscy2  The maps open at zoom 4, notice that after zoom 6 the text gets larger as the view magnifies the WMS at level 6.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I've needed!